# Write titles in two languages or not?

Tags: discussion, support, language-choice

I wrote some questions using title in Portuguese and English, must I leave the title in only one language and in the question body I put a "title translation"?

---

Eu escrevi algumas questões com títulos em Português e Inglês, no entanto eu não sei se uso apenas um idioma no título e no corpo eu adiciono a tradução do título.

Comment: This same question sparked my meta question, here: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/21/59

Comment: (We can, of course, consider consolidating the two questions if they're too similar)

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar I don't consider it, this is about "titles".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having both languages in the title gets crowded. It makes it harder to quickly scan a list of question titles. Someone who is reading quickly might miss the second half of the title anyway.

Therefore I do not recommend it as a general rule. If you're asking a question in Portuguese, leave the title in Portuguese. If you're asking a question in English, leave the title in English.

We often have bilingual titles on [French Language Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/) but almost never on the main site.

---

Ter ambas as línguas no título deixa-o "abarrotado". Torna-se mais difícil passar os olhos pela lista de títulos das perguntas. De qualquer maneira, alguém que leia depressa poderá deixar passar a segunda parte do título.

Portanto, não recomendo isso como regra geral. Se estiverem a perguntar em português, deixem o título em português. Se estiverem a perguntar em inglês, deixem o título em inglês.

Costumamos ter títulos bilingues no [French Language Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/), mas quase nunca no site principal.

Comment: I understand. Would it be appropriate to ask a question for each language?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/perguntas-semelhantes-escritas-em-idiomas-distintos-devem-ser-consideradas-dup

Comment: Hi, Gilles. Good to see you here. I would really appreciate if you post an answer to [this question](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/43/57).